# Citation Index: existe-t-il dans la science et la langue francophones?

Tags: usage, terminologie

C'est à dire, comment nomme-t-on les moyens pour identifier les auteurs plus cités et les revues scientifiques plus lues? Ni les dictionnaires disponibles, ni même le réseau informatique ne donnent de résultats. Il paraît que « index de citations » n'est pas l'équivalent idéal.

Est-ce que c'est un terme complètement étranger à la science française? Il y a pourtant le concept du [facteur d'impact](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facteur_d%27impact), mais c'est autre chose que ça.

Comment: I can't make sense of what you wrote.

Comment: @dada686 Je crois que mon français est assez intelligible, n' est-ce pas?

Comment: I'm sorry if I came up as rude, that wasn't my intention since my english is not that good. Please tell me what word do you want a translation for and in which context ?

Comment: @dada686 My English is not perfect, either. The question is not just about translation, it's about a concept related to the word as well. The question is about Citation Index: does it exist at all in French language (as a word) and in French science (as a practice)? The term 'index de citation(s)' seems to be not quite perfct, and the 'impact factor', or 'facteur d'impact' is a way different concept.

Comment: La seule chose qui me vient à l'esprit se rapporte à une table des matières, des annales, un appendum ou des Annexes ?    Recherche la définition de ces mots, cela devra aider peut-être.

Comment: @dada686 Non, ils sont les cocepts informatiques, mais 'Citation Index' est un index des auteurs ou des revues cientifiques plus lu(e)s et plus cité(e)s.

Comment: désolé, je n'en sais pas plus :(

Comment: @Manjusri I can't understand your question, either. Could you try in English? We'll help you with the French if you want.

Comment: @dada686 a raison, moi aussi n'arrive pas a comprendre de tout

Comment: @Frenchbeginner Il y a aussi des gens qui l' ont compris.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you are talking about this:

> [Base de données bibliographique](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_de_donn%C3%A9es_bibliographiques)

Comment: Un vif merci, mais non,  par ce terme-là, j'entends le taux de citations des auteurs ou des révues scientifiques.

Comment: [Bibliométrie](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bibliom%C3%A9trie) alors peut-être ?

Sinon, plus spécifiquement, il y a l'[indice h](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indice_H)

Comment: Au cas où : La page sur la bibliométrie parle d'indicateurs de production, d'indicateurs d'impact, d'indicateurs de citation, ainsi que d'indicateurs composites.

Comment: Bibliométrie est le domaine scientifique, mais ce que je veux entendre est seulement un concept. Autrement dit, comment mesure-t-on le niveau d'impact des rechercheurs ou des revues scientifiques?

Comment: Malgré toute sa complicité, ce paraît être de plus proches  du concept de Citation Index. Merci.

Comment: La bibliométrie est un concept et n'est pas réservé au domaine scientifique, comme indiqué sur la page de Wikipedia, même si elle est principalement utilisée en sciences et notamment en recherche. (Et "complicité" n'est probablement pas le terme à employer ici, plutôt "complexité" ?)

Comment: Donc, qu'est ce que c'est un concept? Et si la bibliométrie n'est pas résérvée au domaine scientifique, est-ce que votre réponse est applicable, en parlant du domaine scientifque auquel appartient le concept de Citation Index?

Comment: Oui, "complexité", pas "complicité".

Comment: Oui, on utilise bien le terme de bibliométrie dans le domaine scientifique. Pour s'assurer de l'adéquation du terme au contexte, il serait peut-être bon que vous nous donniez une phrase dans laquelle vous souhaitez placer l'équivalent de Citation Index.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that the expression "Citation Index" often referes to a couple of documents as the "Science Citation Index". It seems that there is not any "official" translation for that word.

However, Linguee shows some articles where it is directly translated as "Index de citations". There does not seem to be any dedicated word in French, but this one is understandable. I don't think anybody would have problems to understand it :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm absolutely not sure if that's even used in the world of scientific publication in French, but such a term could be translated in

> Taux de citation
>
> Indice de citation
>
> Fréquence de citation

These transaltions would carry the idea of ranking authors and articles according to the way they are cited by others.

If you mean the database as a whole, I guess you could use

> Base de citations
>
> Index de citations
>
> Table de citations

Comment: Donc, le terme n'est pas utilisé très souvent dans le monde scientifique des francophones...

Comment: Je ne suis pas suffisamment impliqué dans le monde académique pour en être certain.